# Dynamically decide Winforms or Wpf at startup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winforms

I have a use case where it would be useful to have a single exe that could decide on startup whether it's hosting *only* WPF application code or *only* WinForms code. Once the decision is made, the exe would simply load up one dll (for WinForms) or a different dll (for WPF).

I would like the exe to have as little code (and references) as possible and put most if not all of the application logic in a set of dlls. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
MyApp.exe                <- The exe shim.
MyApp.Core.dll           <- Things and Stuff.
MyApp.Windows.Forms.dll  <- The WinForms dll.
MyApp.Windows.dll        <- The WPF dll.
```

MyApp.exe would reference only the .NET framework assemblies that are common to both WinForms *and* WPF. (so, `System, System.Core, System.Data, System.Xml, etc`) Then it would just dynamically load a reference to either MyApp.Windows.dll or MyApp.Windows.dll which would do the rest of the work.

My questions are:

- What can possibly go wrong?
- I can't find any examples out there. Can you?
- Is it worth the trouble just to avoid having 2 separate exes?

(Basically, a single exe would be really *sexy* and simple for end-users (who are developers), but it's not *completely* necessary. So if this idea is way, way off the beaten path and could potentially cause unusual problems I wouldn't want to do it.)

Thank You.

Comment: That seems like it would be a development nightmare, trying to develop a WPF and WinForms in a single app.  Why not just have a loader that just checks the criterion and invokes one of two other applications: the WPF or WinForms app?

Comment: Well, what in particular is nightmarish about it? That's part of the question so you can go ahead and put your thoughts as an answer if you'd like. When I build a WPF app, I put most of the code in a dll anyway and just App.xaml(.cs) goes in the exe.

Comment: #1, it's not supported.  You either have to add WPF code/references to a WinForms app created in VS or add WinFormst code/references to a WPF app. I don't know what that means to the VS designers.  In addition, any effects to Settings, Resources, or app.config is unknown.

Comment: #1 not supported is the best answer I've heard yet. I'm putting this aside for now and planning on 2 separate exes. No big deal. Thanks.

Comment: Create one version of your app in WinForm. Create another version of your app in WPF. They know as much of each other as Microsoft Words knows about Firefox. Then create a third application (a batch?) that, on whatever criteria, decides which application to run.

Answer (score 2):

On you decision assembly just call [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) and run the proper App. Don't mix the things on development.

Comment: This is the only viable option if you want to go down this route (though I can't imagine a scenario that'd call for it), as WPF apps don't have a "traditional" external entry-point method -- the entry point is implemented by the `App` generated class, which would have to be in the DLL in your case, and that doesn't work.